# don´t understand external storage

Tags: java, android

I am making my first application and I still have some problems when assimilating certain concepts. The idea is to store the data captured by the phone's accelerometer and store it in the external storage for later processing with a mathematical program. As you can see in the code, I have tried to create two methods for external and internal storage, being the first of these the one that gives me error. Where have I gone wrong? Where is the generated .txt supposed to be stored? Thank you very much for your help.

Here is the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the .java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    TextView x,y,z;
    EditText dnombre;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private SensorManager acelerometro;
    private long tiempoCreacion;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






        acelerometro=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor=acelerometro.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        //convertimos en variables los displays de pantalla
        x=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xID);
        y=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yID);
        z=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.zID);
        dnombre = findViewById(R.id.nombreArchivo);




    }
     public void onResume(View vista){
        super.onResume();
        acelerometro.registerListener(this,sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
         tiempoCreacion = System.currentTimeMillis();


     }


    public void onPause(View vista){
        super.onPause();
        acelerometro.unregisterListener(this);



    }

    // concatenamos los xmil datos que nos entran, como variable solo entran datos xq el nombre lo ponemos nosotros
   public void escribirCsv(String fileContents) {



       //introducimos el nombre del file por la interfaz
       String nombre = dnombre.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(nombre, Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //guardar en almacenamiento externo
    public void escribirCsvEx(String fileContents) {




        String nombre = dnombre.getText().toString();
        File datos = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "datos");
        if (!datos.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("directorio no creado");
        }

    }


    // comprobaciones de si se puede guardar en almacenamiento externo
    private boolean isExternalStorageWritable(){
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
            System.out.println("es escribible");
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission(String permission){
        int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if(check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            System.out.println("tenemos permisos");
        }
        return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    }



    //guardar en almacenamiento interno
    public void writeFile(String fileContents){

        String nombre = dnombre.getText().toString();
        if(isExternalStorageWritable())// && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            {
            File Dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/DirectorioDatos" );
            if(!Dir.exists()){
                Dir.mkdir();
            }


                File nombre_Archivo = new File(Dir,nombre);


            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nombre_Archivo);
                fos.write(fileContents.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Write to External Storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    /*//crear aceleración resultante
    public void aceResult(double ax,double ay,double az){
     double ax2= pow(ax,2);
     double ay2= pow(ay,2);
     double az2= pow(az,2);
     double atot= ax2+ay2+az2;
     double aresul= sqrt(atot);
    }*/




    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        //valores a la consola
        /*System.out.println("text");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); //da valor en la consola no en movil*/


        long tiempo = System.currentTimeMillis()-tiempoCreacion;
        if(tiempo<=3000) {

            String tiempoString = Long.toString(tiempo);
            this.x.setText("X = " + event.values[0]);
            this.y.setText("Y = " + event.values[1]);
            this.z.setText("Z = " + event.values[2]);

            //aceleracion resultante
            double ax=event.values[0];
            double ay=event.values[1];
            double az=event.values[2];

            double ax2= pow(ax,2);
            double ay2= pow(ay,2);
            double az2= pow(az,2);
            double atot= ax2+ay2+az2;
            double aresul= sqrt(atot);






            String datos = tiempoString + ";" + event.values[0] + ";" + event.values[1] + ";" + event.values[2] + ";" + aresul + ";" + "\n";

            escribirCsvEx(datos);

            //SystemClock.sleep(7000);


        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
//este no vale
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Post the stacktrace and messages from logcat or other error you have.

Comment: @DavidWasser `problems when assimilating certain concepts.`